# Cross Compiling Google Protobuf for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling

My goal is to generate a libprotobuf.a which is cross-compiled for ARM platform.

I am doing the following:

```
cd deps
git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git protobuf
cd protobuf
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=pwd/../uname -m-linux-gnu
make
make install
cd ../..

cd deps
git clone https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.git protobuf-c
cd protobuf-c
./autogen.sh
mkdir ../pbc-uname -m
cd ../pbc-uname -m
../protobuf-c/configure --prefix=pwd/../uname -m-linux-gnu
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=pwd/../uname -m-linux-gnu/lib/pkgconfig
make
make install
cd ../..

cd deps
mkdir -p pbc-arm
cd pbc-arm
AR_FLAGS="cr" ../protobuf-c/configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --prefix=/opt/autotalks/gcc/arm/poky-st/2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi --disable-protoc PATH=/opt/autotalks/gcc/arm/poky-st/2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH

make PATH=pwd/../uname -m-linux-gnu/bin:$PATH
make install PATH=pwd/../uname -m-linux-gnu/bin:$PATH
cd ../..
```

but I dont see any libprotobuf.a generated.

I only have:

```
duser@192.168.1.28:~/mk5/stack/apps/obu-rsu/cohda/deps/pbc-mk5$ ls protobuf-c/* -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 duser duser   1046 Dec 20 15:58 protobuf-c/libprotobuf-c.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 duser duser    340 Dec 20 15:58 protobuf-c/libprotobuf-c.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 duser duser    308 Dec 20 15:58 protobuf-c/protobuf-c.lo
-rw-r--r-- 1 duser duser 186328 Dec 20 15:58 protobuf-c/protobuf-c.o
```

Am I missing something in order to generate the static cross-compiled library?